# Omit specific values from a named range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a named range that is made up of dynamic values of which I need to omit the zeros prior to averaging.  How would I go about doing this?

```
myRange = (1,3,4,0,4,3,5,0,1)
AVERAGE(myRange) equals 2.333
```

So when I run =AVERAGE(myRange) I am not getting the intended results.

What I would like is to remove the zeroes so I end up with the following:

```
noZeroes(myRange) = (1,3,4,4,3,5,1)
AVERAGE(myRange) equals 3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula to average all of the non-zero values in a range:

```
=SUM(myRange)/COUNTIF(myRange,"<>0")
```

Comment: Where's the facepalm key again?
Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AVERAGEIF(range,criteria,average_range)` in Excel 2007

`Range`    is one or more cells to average, including numbers or names, arrays, or references that contain numbers.

`Criteria`    is the criteria in the form of a number, expression, cell reference, or text that defines which cells are averaged. For example, criteria can be expressed as 32, "32", ">32", "apples", or B4.

`Average_range`    is the actual set of cells to average. If omitted, range is used.

#### Your Solution:

`=AVERAGEIF(myRange,">0") = 3`

OR

`=AVERAGEIF(myRange,"<>0") = 3`